# What does -ex option used in bash | #!/bin/bash -ex mean

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

We are using the script below as user data for EC2 instances. I don't understand what is `-ex` option is being used for?

```
#!/bin/bash -ex

yum update -y
yum groupinstall -y "Web Server" "MySQL Database" "PHP Support"
service httpd start
chkconfig httpd on
```

Comment: See this superuser post: http://superuser.com/questions/195826/bash-shebang-for-dummies

Answer (score 39):

According to [Add tack e x on your bash shebang | `#!/bin/bash -ex`](https://scottlinux.com/2014/08/05/add-tack-e-x-on-your-bash-shebang-binbash-ex/)

> Bash scripts can use various options on the shebang (#!/bin/bash). A more common one is: ‘#!/bin/bash -ex’.
>
> `-e`  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
> `-x`  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.
>
> In short, adding **`-ex`** to your **`#!/bin/bash`** will give verbose output and also will abort your script immediately if part of the script fails.

Answer (score 23):

This is just another way of saying :

```
#!/bin/bash 

set -ex # Added line

yum update -y
yum groupinstall -y "Web Server" "MySQL Database" "PHP Support"
service httpd start
chkconfig httpd on
```

[[ bash manual ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html) says :

> All of the single-character options used with the set builtin (see The
>   Set Builtin) can be used as options when the shell is invoked

[[ set reference ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin)  says :

> set allows you to change the values of shell options and set the
>   positional parameters, or to display the names and values of shell
>   variables.
>
> -x
>
> Print a trace of simple commands, for commands, case commands, select
>   commands, and arithmetic for commands and their arguments or
>   associated word lists after they are expanded and before they are
>   executed. The value of the PS4 variable is expanded and the resultant
>   value is printed before the command and its expanded arguments.
>
> -e
>
> Exit immediately if a pipeline (see Pipelines), which may consist of a
>   single simple command (see Simple Commands), a list (see Lists), or a
>   compound command (see Compound Commands) returns a non-zero status.